# "No such column" when searching in sqlite3 in python

Tags: python, sqlite

My table, "info", has 4 columns: bp, key, exp and job. I'm trying to create a function that searches for a term within a specified column:

*Edit: Different problem, see 2nd code and 2nd error below*

```
def search2(query, field):

    search_string = query    

    if field == "bp":
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM info WHERE bp="+search_string)
    elif field == "key":
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM info WHERE key="+search_string)
    elif field == "exp":
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM info WHERE exp="+search_string)
    elif field == "job":
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM info WHERE job="+search_string)
```

However, this raises an error, with "test" as search string and "bp" as column:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\Programs\time_database.py", line 32, in search2
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM info WHERE bp="+search_string)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: test
```

And by the way, "test" wasn't intended to be a column. I want it to be a search string that *matches* the specified column...

*EDIT*

Thanks Martijn Pieters for that, but now another error has surfaced. My code now is:

```
def search2(query, field):

    search_string = query    

    if field == "bp":
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM info WHERE job=?", search_string)
    elif field == "key":
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM info WHERE key="+search_string)
    elif field == "exp":
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM info WHERE exp="+search_string)
    elif field == "job":
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM info WHERE job="+search_string)
```

And the error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\gummi\Programs\time_database.py", line 32, in search2
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM info WHERE job=?", search_string)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement         uses 1, and there are 4 supplied.
```

Comment: Have you tried to execute the resulting query with the `sqlite3` command line tool on your database? Most probably you're just missing some quotes around `test`.

Comment: That was perhaps better posted as a quick comment on my answer; I had made a small mistake and did not put the `search_string` parameter in a tuple. Updated my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not quoting the search string, and the database is interpreting it as a column name instead.

Use query parameters, these quote your search string automatically:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM info WHERE job=?", search_string)
```

Next, if the `field` (column) value is not coming from an untrusted source (such as a web page) you can interpolate it directly into your query:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM info WHERE %s=?" % field, (search_string,))
```

Now you no longer need all the branching.

If the `field` value *does* come from an untrusted source, the simplest thing is to just test if it is an allowed value:

```
def search2(query, field):
    if field not in set(['bp', 'key', 'exp', 'job']):
        raise ValueError('No such column ' + field)    
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM info WHERE %s=?" % field, (query,))
```

Comment: Also, protect you from little bobby tables.

Comment: Pardon the language, but sweet Mother Marie. That was fast.

Comment: @user1614466 -- That's Martijn Pieters for you.  If you find that this answers you question, don't hesitate to mark it as accepted (click the little checkmark next to the answer).  That lets others know that your problem has been solved.

Comment: /me blows the smoke from his gun barrel.

Comment: Sorry but I still have a problem Martijn. :D

I used the code you provided in the edit and it now looks like this:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\gummi\Programs\time_database.py", line 31, in search2
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM info WHERE %s=?" % (field, search_string))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: @user1614466: that's because you didn't copy my code correctly; look closely at `field` and `search_string`. I do `somestring % a_value` in one place, and then the other argument to execute is `(other_value,)`, that's a one-item tuple (to fill the one questionmark parameter in the query).